# Searching a specift data on a table

Tags: mysql

I have to search in a table, all the photos that start with the code "2950".
Example: 2950_1, 2950_2 ...
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `vnd_imovelfoto` WHERE `codigofoto` = 2950
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) comparison operator in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   vnd_imovelfoto 
WHERE  codigofoto LIKE '2950%'
```